# Lambda ハンドラー外部でRDSへの接続をした場合、最新データが取れない

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, pymysql

aws lambdaでpymysqlを使ってRDSに接続を行っています。

handlerの外に接続処理をしておけば、パフォーマンスは向上しますが、その状態では他のlambdaから作成されたレコードとは取得できず、直接修正したレコードの内容も反映されないですね。

AWS公式ドキュメントにもhandlerの外に接続することを推奨しているみたいですが、調べてみても速度向上の記事しかありません。かなり大きな問題かと思いますが。。

何かご存じでしょうか。

**追記**

RDSの複数のテーブルにおいて、データを作成するAPI Gateway -> Lambdaと取得するAPI Gateway -> Lambdaがあります。
このAPIは頻繁に実行されていますので、ほとんどがWarm startです。

データが取得できない問題とは、例えば以下のような状態です。

- テーブルAに一つのレコードがある状態で、取得用のAPIから登録されているレコードを取得。
- その後、登録用APIで新規レコードを作成。
- その後、取得用APIでデータを取得しようとしたら、前のレコードしか取れない。

取得用のLambdaがDB接続した時点で存在しているレコードしか取れないのかなという感じでしたが、合っていますでしょうか。
一つのテーブルだけではなく、二つのテーブルで発生しました。

登録用のLambdaも取得用のLambdaもRdsのConnectを以下のようにしています。

```py
# Rdsの接続と作成/取得メソッドをrds.pyにRdsというクラスで定義
from rds import Rds

# DB接続処理
Rds.connect()

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # データ作成や取得メソッドを実行
    Rds.insert()
```

Rdsクラスではconnectをクラス内のglobal変数に入れて、使いまわしています。

Comment: 「その状態では他のlambdaから作成されたレコードとは取得できず、直接修正したレコードの内容も反映されない」というのがよくわかりませんでした。接続維持ではなくてデータの更新が何かしらうまくいっていないのかなと思います。簡単でいいのでご自身の書いたコードも合わせて質問に追記いただいてもいいですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。説明が足りず、申し訳ございませんでした。仕事中に焦ってまました。。内容を修正しておきましたので、ご確認お願いいたします。